# Convert php files with html4 tags to xhtml using tidy

Tags: php, xhtml, debian, tidy

I'm trying to use Tidy to convert a lot of html4 tags in php files to xhtml, like this in Debian:

```
tidy -indent -o xhtmltestnew.php -asxhtml xhtmltest.php
```

I have two problems.

1) Can I make tidy ignore my PHP code? It messes a lot of it up by converting it.

2) For some reason I can't make it close img and br tags - can this be done?

Should I try another approach instead?

Comment: tidy's not php-aware, as far as I know. it'd also be HIGHLY non-trivial to make it so. consider some html like this: `echo '<a', ' href', '="..."', '</a>'`. perfectly fine html, but it's not going to look like it to tidy... basically you'd have to build a complete PHP interpreter/parser into tidy to make something like this work properly.

Comment: Why convert to xhtml when html5 is the standard that is being used now and allows you to omit />

Comment: It's rather old code I'm converting(and lots of it) and I'm trying to get as close to w3 validating as possible - xhtml is possible without completely rewriting everything - sadly html5 isn't. Maybe I should try some regex to catch some of the minor stuff.

Comment: I'll probably use the find & sed approach as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242066/how-can-i-validate-large-numbers-of-files-with-search-and-replace